# How to use Stylance with Leptos?

Tags: css, leptos

I've been trying my best to use a scoped CSS file (using [Stylance](https://github.com/basro/stylance-rs)) for styling a [Leptos](https://leptos.dev/) component, and it seems to work but the styles simply don't apply. The file is read correctly by Stylance and the module is generated correctly, but on the render, the styles aren't there.

Here is my project's structure:

```
Cargo.toml
index.html
dist/ ...
target/ ...
src/
  - lib.rs
  - main.rs
  - test.module.css
```

In `main.rs` I have the following code:

```rust
use leptos::*;
use my_crate_name::*; // to import my stuff from lib.rs

pub fn main() {
    mount_to_body(|| view! { <App /> });
}

#[component]
fn App() -> impl IntoView {
    view! { <MyLibraryCustomComponent /> }
}
```

In `lib.rs`:

```rust
use stylance::import_crate_style;

import_crate_style!(style, "src/test.module.css");

#[component]
pub fn MyLibraryCustomComponent() -> impl IntoView {
    view! { <h1 class=style::test>"This is a title"</h1> }
}
```

And finally here is my `test.module.css` that I wrote:

```css
.test {
    color: blue;
}
```

I serve the app on localhost:8080 (using `trunk serve`) and with the dev console I can see that my `<h1>` element has the class `test-aRandomHash`. So far this is normal and intented. What's not normal is that I can't see anywhere my "color: blue" style. The `<h1>` element simply doesn't have it, like it didn't exist, which is weird since Stylance has read the file and extracted the class.

I'm new to Leptos and Stylance so I've basically no idea what I'm doing. The documentation for using Stylance with Leptos is very small and basically non-existent (https://book.leptos.dev/interlude_styling.html#stylance-scoped-css-written-in-css-files).

Note that I'm not using Nightly.

> **EDIT**: I tried using :global(.test) in the css file and it didn't change a thing. My h1 element isn't blue.

Comment: Are you including the generated css in your page?

Comment: What do you mean by "generated css" ? I didn't generate any CSS, I wrote the file "test.module.css", and I'm not sure why there is a ".module.", I just supposed it was a convention. Also, what do you mean by "in your page" ? Since I'm building a library for leptos, I'd like the CSS to come with my library, and ideally I'd like to use SCSS in an external file.

Comment: stylance presumably generates a css file based on your css module. You have to include this file.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I had misunderstood the documentation of Stylance. I had to create a bundle with stylance-cli and use this bundle. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use it though, but I eventually settled on another solution (https://trunkrs.dev/assets/#css)